# Wifi (Broadcom BCM43225) not working on 14.04 LTS x64

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have this on my Acer 3820 Notebook:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v1.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1073] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0364]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4357] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H103.00 Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e021]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

And it's not working. I cannot find my router and if I found it I'm not able to connect, I just get the message that I should retype my password. I was testing TAILS on this Notebook as live cd and with that there are absolutely no problems with connectig to the wifi. So Ubuntu 14.04 got some driver problems?

I was reading this big thread here:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Before checking things I just tried the b43 driver, something like this

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Did not work out, not even able to see wifi connections. After reading the postings in the like above I was really confused, but I thought the bcmwl driver is the right one that I need. So I removed the **firmware-b43** a tried like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Well with this I do not see my wifi. I see like other 10 wifi spots, just mine not. Tried to connect to somewhere else, it's not working :/

I'm really confused about this stuff. Does this help?

```
iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  8 
dm_crypt               23177  0 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
btusb                  32412  0 
bluetooth             391136  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
wl                   6367819  0 
acer_wmi               32522  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 acer_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
snd_hda_intel          56451  5 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
dm_multipath           22873  0 
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
scsi_dh                14882  1 dm_multipath
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143109  0 
kvm                   451552  1 kvm_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
joydev                 17381  0 
fglrx                8085343  77 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
cfg80211              484040  1 wl
serio_raw              13462  0 
amd_iommu_v2           19054  1 fglrx
lpc_ich                21080  0 
snd                    69322  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 18627  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
shpchp                 37032  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
dm_mirror              22135  0 
dm_region_hash         20862  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18411  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
psmouse               106678  0 
ahci                   25819  3 
libahci                32716  1 ahci
atl1c                  46086  0 
wmi                    19177  1 acer_wmi
video                  19476  1 acer_wmi
```

I have absolutely no idea what else I could post. Also no idea what to do, any help please? Thank you

Comment: Post the results from `uname -a`

Comment: Linux corei3 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

```bsh
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Reboot and if Wi-Fi still isn't working, you can blacklist a couple modules:

```bsh
echo "blacklist b43" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then it should work unless you blacklisted one of the needed modules.